# SQL Syntax Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong with this sql statement

```
select top(1) 
  OrderNumber 
 from (select top(5) 
         OrderNumber 
       from SomeTable
       where TreePath='tests' 
       order by OrderNumber asc)
```

Any Ideas?

Regards,
Byron Cobb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to alias the derived table

```
select top 1 
  myDerivedTable.OrderNumber 
 from (select top 5 
         OrderNumber 
       from TABLE 
       where TreePath='tests' 
       order by OrderNumber asc) myDerivedTable
order by myDerivedTable.OrderNumber
```

Comment: Perfect - Thanks! SQL always gets the better of me :(

Comment: As it stands this answer is not deterministic. It needs an `order by` on the outer query as well.